# Javascript - how to iterate through nested array with arrays and objects and why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, hoisting

I have an array with many nested arrays and objects. My code doesn't work and after looking at it over and over again, I don't understand why. Its hard to explain what I mean (sorry if my title question was also not very clear, but I didn't know how to explain what I mean, if I don't know whats wrong in my code), so I put my 2 questions insight my code as comments - I hope its understandable! Thanks a lot for any ideas.

```
var trips= [{
   "Air": {
        "OriginDestinationOptions": {
            "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                "Flight": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "JFK"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }, {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "TXL"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }

                },
                {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "TXL"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHR"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }

                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 915
            }, {
                "Flight": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHR"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LAX"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }, {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LAX"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "TXL"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                },
                 {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "TXL"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHR"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }

                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 1425
            }]
        },
        "DirectionInd": "Return"
    }
}, 
{
    "Air": {
        "OriginDestinationOptions": {
            "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                "Flight": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "JFK"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }, {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHR"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 915
            }, {
                "Flight": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHR"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }, {
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SVO"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "JFK"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "SU"
                    }
                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 1125
            }]
        },
        "DirectionInd": "Return"
    }        
}];
```

My code:

```
var flightObjects = [];

     function getAirportNameToLocation(obj) {
         var allTrips = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                  

      allTrips.push(obj[i].Air.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption)
         }

         for (var i = 0; i < allTrips.length; i++) {

             var toDestinationFlightsTemp = [];
             var returnFlightsTemp = [];
             //first FlightsSegment object --> to destination flights
             var flightsToLoc = allTrips[i][0];

             //second FlightsSegment object --> return flights
             var returnFlights = allTrips[i][1];

             console.log(toDestinationFlightsTemp)
```

1.) when I console log 'toDestinationFlights'-I get an empty array, but 2 lines below when I push ALSO (same as I console log before) toDestinationFlights to my flightObjects object and return that object, Im actually not getting back an empty array, but values. I don't know why.

```
             console.log("test", toDestinationFlightsTemp)
             flightObjects.push({
```

2.) What was intended here: toDestinationFlights: toDestinationFlightsTemp.concat(returnFlights[0]) - I want the values from toDestinationFlightsTemp and the first value from returnFlightsTemp this doesnt work because again, somehow Im getting an empty array

```
                 toDestinationFlights: toDestinationFlightsTemp, //This for whatever reason works fine
                 returnFlights: returnFlightsTemp
             })

             flightsToLoc.Flight.forEach(function(flightTo, i) {
                 toDestinationFlightsTemp.push(flightTo.DepartureAirport.LocationCode);
             })

             returnFlights.Flight.forEach(function(flightTo, i) {
             returnFlightsTemp.push(flightTo.DepartureAirport.LocationCode)
             })
         }
         toDestinationFlightsARIVALTemp = toDestinationFlightsTemp.concat(returnFlightsTemp[0]);
     }
     getAirportNameToLocation(trips)

     flightObjects;
```

Comment: Make your code runnable and convert your notes into comments, it is quite hard to debug such amount of code inside the head

Comment: So what information are you exactly trying to extract from your dataset? `getAirportNameToLocation` tells me you want an array with all the 'DepartureAirport->LocationCode'?

Comment: I just tested your code, in my case both console logs give an empty array, which is not surprising since you explicitely create it empty for each i 4 lines above.

Comment: You are creating/setting `toDestinationFlightsTemp` and `returnFlightsTemp` inside a loop then attempt to use it for `toDestinationFlightsARIVALTemp` outside the loop; this is not safe

Comment: I have refactored your code to make it more functional, hopefully this will help you spot which piece of logic is not as you expect https://jsbin.com/zolixiqude/edit?js,console

Comment: I agree with Manuel, you should first clearly define what type of information you want to collect. It looks like you want to list all departures codes for each trip. If I'm right, you have your data in the `flightObjects` variable.

Comment: @Flying what do you mean with unable? if you just copy paste the entire code, it runs.

Comment: @Paul S. your code returns me exactly the same as mine so Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: @javascripting you have text comments in the middle of your code listing into question, so direct copy/paste will not work

Comment: @javascripting It means : make an embedded code snippet please.

Comment: Sorry Im not quite sure what to define regarding the info? I have 2 questions (the first 1 I just edited, sorry it was phrased unclear) and in my other question (2.) ) I explain what I want which is concat one array with the first value of my other array.. If you could look again at my both questions, let me know if its still unclear what I mean

Comment: @Flying https://jsfiddle.net/codingcodingcoding/3ta06f35/ ( jsfiddle doesn't do much clearly as I don't have html), but you could copy paste the code

Comment: @javascripting We could, however you are requesting a free service here, then have a little respect for the readers.

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why you're seeing what looks like unexpected behavior:

First you define variable outside the function `flightObjects`. Then you make a loop loop that will run twice:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allTrips.length; i++)
```

Then inside that loop you initialize a variable:

```
var toDestinationFlightsTemp = [];
```

This gets redefined every time through the loop. You `console.log` it and it's still an empty array because you haven't touched it.

Next you push that empty array onto the global `flightObjects`:

```
flightObjects.push({
            toDestinationFlights: toDestinationFlightsTemp, //This for whatever reason works fine
            returnFlights: returnFlightsTemp
        })
```

This doesn't actually work fine — `flightObjects.toDestinationFlights` is now pointing to the same empty array as `toDestinationFlightsTemp`. The first time through the loop, both print empty arrays. But then, after you've `console.log`ed it, you add elements to it:

```
 flightsToLoc.Flight.forEach(function(flightTo, i) {
            toDestinationFlightsTemp.push(flightTo.DepartureAirport.LocationCode);
        })
```

Since `toDestinationFlightsTemp` and `flightObjects.toDestinationFlights` point to the same array, both `toDestinationFlightsTemp` and `flightObjects.toDestinationFlights` have the element you pushed into the array.

*Now* you loop again. On this loop you redefine `toDestinationFlightsTemp` and point it to a new empty array. But `flightObjects` still points to the same array and has a reference to the elements you pushed the *first* time through your loop. So now  when you get to the `console.log`s `toDestinationFlightsTemp` is empty, but `flightObjects` still has the elements you pushed the first time though the loop. So you see those when you `console.log` it.

I *think* what you were intending to do would happen if you moved this up before you try to push the values into `flightObjects`:

```
        flightsToLoc.Flight.forEach(function(flightTo, i) {
            toDestinationFlightsTemp.push(flightTo.DepartureAirport.LocationCode);
        })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear answer!!! It makes sense and now since I moved up my forEach loops it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Here is how to make an embedded code snippet on Stackoverflow :

```js
var trips = [{
  "Air": {
    "OriginDestinationOptions": {
      "OriginDestinationOption": [{
        "Flight": [{
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "JFK"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "TXL"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "TXL"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }],
        "ElapsedTime": 915
      }, {
        "Flight": [{
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LAX"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LAX"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "TXL"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "TXL"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }],
        "ElapsedTime": 1425
      }]
    },
    "DirectionInd": "Return"
  }
}, {
  "Air": {
    "OriginDestinationOptions": {
      "OriginDestinationOption": [{
        "Flight": [{
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "JFK"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }],
        "ElapsedTime": 915
      }, {
        "Flight": [{
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "LHR"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }, {
          "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "SVO"
          },
          "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "JFK"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "SU"
          }
        }],
        "ElapsedTime": 1125
      }]
    },
    "DirectionInd": "Return"
  }
}];

var codesForEachTrip = [];
for (let i = 0; i < trips.length; i++) {
  let trip = trips[i];
  let origDestOpts = trip.Air.OriginDestinationOptions;
  let origDestOpt = origDestOpts.OriginDestinationOption;
  let outwardJourney = origDestOpt[0].Flight;
  let inwardJourney = origDestOpt[1].Flight;
  let codesForThisTrip = {
    outwardJourney: [],
    inwardJourney: []
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < outwardJourney.length; i++) {
    let sub = outwardJourney[i];
    let code = sub.DepartureAirport.LocationCode;
    codesForThisTrip.outwardJourney.push(code);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < inwardJourney.length; i++) {
    let sub = inwardJourney[i];
    let code = sub.DepartureAirport.LocationCode;
    codesForThisTrip.inwardJourney.push(code);
  }
  codesForEachTrip.push(codesForThisTrip);
}
console.log(codesForEachTrip);
```

Comment: @javascripting When I press "Run code snippet" I don't see any error.

Comment: I copy pasted your code into real and it also throws me an error.

Comment: @javascripting Copy-paste is not so easy after all ? ;-)

Comment: haha copy paste is pretty simple but there is an error in your code and thats the problem: 'Unexpected identifier 'i''

Comment: It's probably the `let i` are you running a browser that doesn't speak es6?

Comment: @javascripting I'm done with this post, hopefully you learned how to make an embedded code snippet :-P More help : https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Im glad, you're done. Please Understand that adding code snippets makes sense in cases where you need to see the UI, if its pure code, it doesn't make sense to add it. If it makes sense for you because you think just copy paste my code, tell me in a normal way. You left tons of coments complaining about something that doesn't make sense, being rude, providing a solution that does not work.  If you don't like my post or don't know the solution, just ignore my post, don't spam my post with rude comments. All the best

Comment: @javascripting When we ask for something more readable you imply that we should make an effort. I think it's rude and I don't like that indeed. My reaction was not so smart though, sorry :-D